# Samsung Music app is not sending playback broadcasts within newer versions

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

It seems like that within the release of newer versions of the [Samsung Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.music&hl=en) app (example: v16.2.20.19), the app itself stopped sending broadcasts related to **playback state** changes, **playback completed**, and **meta change**s.

I tried registering multiple actions to keep receiving broadcasts from it:

- `"com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playbackcomplete"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.music.metachanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.music.playbackcomplete"`;
- `"com.samsung.music.playstatechanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.metachanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.playbackcomplete"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.playstatechanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.android.metachanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.android.playbackcomplete"`;
- `"com.samsung.sec.android.playstatechanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.MusicPlayer.metachanged"`;
- `"com.samsung.MusicPlayer.playbackcomplete"`;
- `"com.samsung.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged"`;
- `"com.sec.android.music.state.META_CHANGED"`.

but they are not working anymore.

---

What are the **new actions** that Samsung is using on the new releases of their app? I tried to spot them, but I had no success.